# Beamerposter: Span two columns with Figure

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I've been trying to get this done for the past several hours. This is my current situation:

[image: Latex messup]

As you can see, the figure at the mid-right of the poster is cutting off. So, how can I fix this?

I assume it has something to do with getting the image over two columns. Any standard ways to do this? `figure*` doesn't seem to work (getting an undefined environment error).

Simplest is best - as usual, running on incredibly tight schedule.

Comment: could you show us the code for what you have so far? :)

Comment: Yes, I can. Sorry I didn't post it.

Comment: No code: can't really help :-(